# Permanently convert datetime to date

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database with a datetime field. I'd like to permanently convert it to a date field (i.e. remove the time element). What is the best way to go about that? Is there a way to do it in place without having to dump the table into a new table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you mean a timestamp with "datetime".

```
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN bar TYPE date;
```

Answer (score 3):

Create new temporary field and `UPDATE yourtable SET newfield = oldfield::date` with proper conversion function and then just remove old field and rename the new field.

Comment: This is functionally equivalent to ALTER TABLE (modulo any constraints  or similar covering the column) but the implementations are different...